# Proving that the multiplication operator is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I was looking at this exercise:
a) Let $f_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $L^p(x,\mu)$. Prove that there exists a subsequence that converges pointwise $\mu$-almost everywhere.
b) Let p $\in [1,\infty], d\ge1$, and $m:\mathbb R^d\rightarrow \mathbb K$ be measurable. 
$$A:dom(A)\rightarrow L^p(\mathbb R^d), Af(x):=m(x)f(x)$$ is the multiplication operator with dom(A):={$f \in L^p(\mathbb R^d)|mf \in L^p(\mathbb R^d)$}.
Show that A is closed.

I could already show a) and the general idea of b) in combination with a) is also clear to me, but I can't quite write it out in full. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT** Just unwrap the definition. Take a sequence $f_n\in L^p$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_p\to 0$ and $\|mf_n-g\|_p\to 0$. Use point a) to show that $g=mf$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Take $=(f_n,Af_n)=(f_n,mf_n) \to (f,g)$ where convergence is in $L^p$. Then there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $f_{n_k}\to f$ a.e. To prove $f \in D(A)$, we use Fatou's Lemma:
$$\int |{f^{p}m^{p}}|d\mu \leq \liminf_{k \to \infty}\int |f_{n_k}m|^{p}d\mu= \liminf_{k \to \infty}\|Af_{n_k}\|_p^{p}$$
Which is finite since $\{Af_{n_k}\}_k$ is convergent in $L^p$ (hence bounded). Thus $fm \in L^p$ and $f \in D(A)$. To prove $g=fm$ a.e, we use the same trick. Since $mf_{n}\to g$ in $L^p$, every subsequence does an hence $mf_{n_k}\to g$ in $L^p$. Thus

$$\|{g-mf}\|^{p}=\int \lim_{k \to \infty}|g-mf_{n_k}|^{p}\leq \liminf_{k \to \infty}\int |g-mf_{n_k}|^{p}=\liminf_{k \to \infty}\|g-mf_{n_k}\|_p^{p}=0$$
thus $g=mf$ a.e and hence $A$ is closed.